# How to check if window is opened and close it

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, singleton

I am working on **C# winforms**.

I have function `Validate()` which is present in the CS file. When I call function `Validate()` it opens ErrorForm using

```
ErrorForm ew = new ErrorForm(Errors); // Errors is list<string>
ew.Show();
```

But when I call it again, a new window opens and my previous window is open too. I have to close that window manually.

Is there any method available such that if I call `validate()` again, it will close the current `ErrorForm` and will open new `ErrorForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
var f1=Application.OpenForms["ErrorForm"];       
if(f1!=null) 
  f1.Close(); 

f1=  new ErrorForm(Errors);
f1.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, a *pseudocode*..

```
public class MyClass 
{
    ErrorForm ew = null; 

    public void Validate() 
    {
       if(ew !=null && !ew.IsDisposed) 
          ew.Close(); 

       ew =  new ErrorForm(Errors);
       ew.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have declared ew=null & because of that every time ErrorForm is called, ew becomes null and  in the if() loop ew.Close() is not getting executed...

Comment: @Sangram: the variable ew is set to Null only once, as this is class member. After this it will never become null. If it's not you're talking about, please clarify.

Comment: I got it. ew is called from another class that's why it will work. U are right. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You may use following collection accessible as static property:
`Application.OpenForms`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is calling `ew.ShowDialog(this)` which keeps the ErrorForm on top of your main form.

If you really want to call `Form.Show()` method, you could implement [Singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) in ErrorForm and call GetInstance. In the GetInstance method you can close it or reuse it.

```
public class ErrorForm 
{
   private static ErrorForm instance;

   private ErrorForm() {}

   public static Singleton GetInstance()
   {
      if (instance == null)
      {
         instance = new ErrorForm();
      }
      else //OR Reuse it
      {
          instance.Close(); 
          instance = new ErrorForm();
      }
      return instance;      
   }

   public Errors ErrorMessages
   {
      set {...}
   }
}
```

In the validate method

```
public void Validate() 
    {
       ErrorForm ef = ErrorForm.GetInstance();
       ef.ErrorMessages = errors;
       ef.Show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **ShowDialog()**